# Dispatch action on the createAsyncThunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I hava a thunk action was created by `createAsyncThunk`. I want to dispatch an action before call api to update state.

I don't want use action `getProducts.pending` because I want dispatch `actionLoading()` for other  thunk actions.

How I can i do it? Thanks!

```
export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk("getProducts", async () => {

  // I want dispatch action actionCallAPIPending like that
  // dispatch(actionLoading());
  const response = await axios.get("api");
  return response;
});
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do it like this with the second param of callback function in the `createAsyncThunk`:

```
export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk("getProducts", async (_, thunkAPI) => {
  thunkAPI.dispatch(actionLoading());
  const response = await axios.get("api");
  return response;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As the createStore method got deprecated I was looking for a solution to migrate an existing project to use [@reduxjs/toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and in the same time to set up a new one.

I found [@Viet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6108390/viet)'s
answer very useful, although to be complete I would like to mention another way of using Async Thunks just to have it in the same thread for people who end up here and might would find it useful.

You still can create an Async Thunk without createAsyncThunk, but this way you cannot rely on the extraReducers as a downside.

```
export const getProducts = (): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(actionLoading());

  try {
    const response = await axios.get("api");
    // return the response or store it
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    // handle the error
    console.warn(error)
  }

  dispatch(actionLoading());
};
```

Comment: This is just the standard way to create thunks without using `createAsyncThunk` API right.

Comment: Yes it is. Wanted to point out that it's still available and not deprecated. Came handy for the migration.

Comment: yeah, some times createAsyncThunk is overkill

Answer (score 3):

in the callback of **createAsyncThunk** , from second parameter you can destruct the dispatch.

```
 export const asyncthunk = createAsyncThunk(
      "ACTION",
      async (_,{dispatch) => {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get("api")
          dispatch(anotherAction())
          return data;
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      }
    );
```